# Cut the url from the questionmark

Tags: node.js, regex

I read the new topics from an IPB forum and I get this result when I want to get the topic link:

```
http://1234.23123/forum/topic/2-rgewgreg/?do=findComment&comment=2
```

How can I cut this **?do=findComment&comment=2** from the url?
It is dynamic so it would be nice if it recognize the questionmark and then delete the rest of the url and the questionmark.

Comment: please post what you have tried

Comment: wht language  you are using

Comment: I get ?do=findComment&comment=2 but I want cut/remove that from the url.

@Avinash Yeah the problem is that I don't know how to start.

Comment: @ParikshitSharma as you can see in tags that node.js.

Comment: Try [https?:\/\/.*\/(?=\?)](https://regex101.com/r/eKv7LU/3/)

Comment: This is tagged node.js, You should be using [url](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/url.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you dont need to use a regex for that you can use

```
let id = "http://1234.23123/forum/topic/2-rgewgreg/?do=findComment&comment=2"; 
let removeStr = id.substr(id.indexOf('?'));
console.log(id.split(removeStr)[0]);
```

output : `http://1234.23123/forum/topic/2-rgewgreg/`

Comment: This fails if there is a `?` in the substring, such as `?do=findComment&co?mment=2`

Comment: @UnbearableLightness now it should work with your example as well

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following.

```
var a = 'http://1234.23123/forum/topic/2-rgewgreg/?do=findComment&comment=2';
console.log(a.replace(/\?.*/g,''));
```

Comment: I get do=findComment&comment=2 but I want cut/remove that from the url.

Comment: @SoulLeader, sorry I didn't get, after using `replace` you are getting the expected output correct? Kindly do let me know more on same what you required?

Comment: DOWN VOTER, please mention the reason for down vote here?

Comment: @SoulLeader, please check my code now and let me know if this helps you?

Comment: Hmm I get now ?do=findComment&comment=2 .

Comment: @SoulLeader, sorry I got it vice versa, check my code now? It should give you before `?` now?

Comment: @DOWN VOTER, I have correct my answer now(I got it vice versa, please remove down voter if looks good now)?

Answer (score -1):

you can use Substring function
like this

string.substring(starposition,length);

example
in case of php

```
  var str="http://1234.23123/forum/topic/2-rgewgreg/?do=findComment&comment=2";
    var res= str.substring(0,str.indexof("?")-1);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Hmm unfortunately it is not php. As you can see in tags that it is node.js :(

Comment: but you did not mention it in your question

Comment: Do I need mention in my question when there is node.js tag? :o

Comment: various peoples uses wrong tags and readers don't pay attention on tags so it is  good to mention it in question

Comment: Hmm I see. Next time I will mention the language then. :)